# Is there a simple Flash applet that just displays video coming from a local webcam?

Tags: flash, microsoft-powerpoint, webcam

I'm looking to display a live webcam feed in a PowerPoint presentation in the most portable way possible (I can't install anything on the PC). It seems the easiest way to do this would be to embed a Flash object displaying video from the webcam, but I can't find anything that does just this. Anyone here know of one or can whip one up themselves quickly?